# How to start Sygic Navigation from code

Tags: android, navigation

Im not sure this is actually allowed here, but since I usually go to StackOverflow and search for answers (and in many cases find the answers) I thought I would ask a question and then answer it myself =)

So, I have Sygic Navigation om my HTC Hero, and since I need to start that app from code (and then use the API to control it) I did some investigation on how to start it - what intent to use.

So, the question is: what Intent or Activity should I use to start the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.sygic.drive","com.sygic.drive.SygicDriveActivity");
startActivity(i);
```

=)

Comment: Unless Sygic officially supports this, bear in mind that it might change in future releases of their application, causing yours to break.

Comment: I actually asked Sygic for the "path" above, they gave me different from above, but they didnt really know either =) It might very well stop functioning if they change it, but we are gonna detect that if and when it happens =) thx!

Answer (score 2):

This is the official answer to this question:
http://help.sygic.com/entries/22207668-Developers-Only-Sygic-implementation-to-your-app-Android-SDK-iPhone-SDK-Url-Handler-

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Sygic can also be launched by using geo uri but the application seems to ignore all of the parameters this uri supports.