# Start external app/Activity and add my own header?

Tags: android, navigation

I am using Sygic Navigation on my HTC Hero. I can start it by calling the correct intent as I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076093/how-to-start-sygic-navigation-from-code). Now, Sygic starts in fullscreen-mode and I cannot use the BACK-button to go back to my previous Activity (don't ask me why).

The question is: is there some trick or way so I can control how that Sygic Activity is started? I want to add my own "header" on top; the header contains my buttons for navigation. It would be great if I could add that header, then have Sygic below that (as the "content" then, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002920/android-layout-how-to-create-a-header-content-layout)).

Answer (score 1):

> Now, Sygic starts in fullscreen-mode
>   and I cannot use the BACK-button to go
>   back to my previous Activity (don't ask
>   me why).

Aw, c'mon! Please can I ask why? Pretty please? :-)

> The question is: is there some trick
>   or way so I can control how that Sygic
>   Activity is started? I want to add my
>   own "header" on top; the header
>   contains my buttons for navigation. It
>   would be great if I could add that
>   header, then have Sygic below that (as
>   the "content" then, as shown here).

No, sorry.

Comment: Is there really no way? A TabActivity essentially has a "header" with an Activity inside..?

Comment: Ah, but it has to be one of *your* activities, not one from another app, which is what the OP was seeking.